# Require a typeclass instance for a haskell associated type synonym

Tags: haskell, typeclass, associated-types

Is it possible to require that an associated type synonym of some class be an instance of some other class? E.g. with something like the following code (doesn't compile!):

```
class Test a where
  type Foo a
  instance Show (Foo a)
```

I would be able to rely on the fact that a `Foo a` is `Show`able regardless of the particular `a` in question.

Obviously I can just add more methods to the class to ensure operations I want on `Foo a`s, but it would be nice to be able to just reuse existing classes.

Comment: You can write `class Show (Foo a) => Test a where type Foo a`, but I don't know whether it's possible to emulate something like `class (forall a. Show (Foo a)) => Test a where type Foo a`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer, thanks to lyxia on #haskell:

```
class (Show (Foo a)) => Test a where
  type Foo a
```